# Can a Rocket be Propelled by Steam and a Cold Sink instead of Exhaust Nozzle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, rocket-science, heat-engine

Is it possible to have a “rocket” which uses steam flowing into the chamber as the pressure source and which uses a cold sink at one end to condense the steam instead of discharging it outside? A regular rocket creates a pressure inside the chamber, and has one side open (partially) to outside pressure (atmospheric/vacuum/whatever) and is pushed forward by the imbalance of forces within the chamber. But if the exhaust via the nozzle is replaced by a cold plate (and is kept cold by some other source of coldness, eg a cryogenic plant) which condenses the steam (e.g. generated by a nuclear reactor) to water, will the imbalance of forces continue to drive the rocket? Or is there some other issue that I am missing? Please dont cite "reacton forces" and Newton's 3rd Law because the 3rd law tells us that there must be a force equal and opposite - but we still need to find what that force is - it is not sufficient to call it the "reaction" to something else!

Answer (score 2):

> A regular rocket creates a pressure inside the chamber, and has one side open (partially) to outside pressure (atmospheric/vacuum/whatever) and is pushed forward by the imbalance of forces within the chamber.

Any rocket works on the principle of conservation of momentum, which is an absolute law in physics, so no need to get tied up with forces. The momentum that the rocket gains will be equal and opposite to the momentum of the mass it exhausts .

> Is it possible to have a “rocket” which uses steam flowing into the chamber as the pressure source and which uses a cold sink at one end to condense the steam instead of discharging it outside?

No, if there is no mass discharged outside no momentum is provided to the system and thus no rocket motion.

Comment: If the steam moved from one chamber to another, its center of mass would move in the rocket's rest frame. The center of mass of the rest of the rocket would have to move in the opposite direction to keep the total center of mass unchanged. So there would be some rocket motion.

Comment: There would be internal rotations and vibrations about the total center of mass. No motion in space.

Comment: Please see comment to David Hammon for more info. In my postualted model, water WILL be discarded, but not as a jet nor against the direction of movement. To Anna, I need to get down to first principals and away from "laws". A regular car with reciprication engine creates movement from chemical reaction. To mmesser, consider the water discarded, but not as a jet.  @mmesser,

Comment: @Stewart It is an irrefutable fact that laws "are " the foundational principles, the axioms, of any mathematical theory modelling physics. If they are not obeyed, the system is unphysical by construction.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there some other issue that I am missing?

**TL;DR:** You are missing that the flow of steam transfers momentum relative to the rocket proper back to the rocket when the steam flow hits the condenser plate.

---

Fleshing out your design a bit, suppose the rocket proper is kilometers long, with a large water tank and a boiler at one end. The boiler end of the system heats the water to a high temperature and uses a de Laval nozzle to expand the escaping steam. The steam flows down a smooth, warm tube to the other end of the rocket, where a condenser plate cools the steam back to water. The collected water is diverted to another large water tank at the condenser end of the rocket. There is no mechanism to transfer water collected at the condenser back to the boiler.

We then fill the tank at the boiler end with water; the tank at the condenser end is initially empty. The rocket is placed in empty space, far from any other disturbing influences (including gravitation). Suppose the two tanks are very large (but very light), large enough so that 99% of the total mass of the rocket+water system is water. This places the center of mass of the rocket+water system very close to the center of the tank at the boiler end. When all of the water has been boiled and condensed at the other end, the center of mass of the rocket+water system will be very close to the center of the tank at the condenser end of the rocket.

There are five states of interest in the operation of the rocket:

1. An initial state prior to starting the boiler, with all of the water at the boiler end of the rocket;
2. An startup transient state where the boiler is operating but the steam flow has has not yet reached the condenser;
3. A steady flow state where water is being boiled at the boiler and condensing at the condenser;
4. A shutdown transient state where the boiler has ceased operation but steam is still flowing; and
5. A final state with all of the water at the condenser end of the rocket.

From the point of view of an observer at rest with the initial configuration of the rocket, the rocket proper must necessarily be moving while steam is flowing. Assuming a constant mass flow rate in the steady flow state, the rocket proper must necessarily be moving at a constant speed with respect to that observer so as to make the total center of mass stationary. The only times the rocket accelerates is during those two transient states. The motion stops when the end state is reached, with the rocket itself displaced from the initial state by roughly the length of the rocket.

Comment: Brilliant visualisation. Question was because I answered on quora to explain the imbalance of forces inside the chamber drives the chemical rocket, not plume of gas.  So if, in your model, water is discarded as a dribble, not a jet (or maybe as a jet pependicular to thrust), and is not retained at condenser end, will the rocked keep accelerating till all the water has been consumed? (remembering that the total mass is decreasing too) Not trying to suggest "perpetual motion ". Only using steam rocket to explain the fundemental forces involved and get away from "Reaction to Action" explanation.

Comment: @Stewart -- As anna v wrote in her answer, rockets work via momentum transfer. This means that if the water leaves the rocket as a dribble, nothing much happens.